# Adding a secondary axis in excell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to add a secondary Y-axis to a bar chart in excel 2016. I can not find the correct menu to add that. Please see the figure. I see some documents on the web but the options don't exists in 2016.

[image]

Comment: Did you try changing the Chart Type to Combo? This should easily allow you to include a Primary & Secondary axis to the chart. Select the two series and opt for suitable Combo Chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

If you have more than one series, you can plot a second Y Axis.

Right click the chart, and select `change chart type`,

Choose a combo chart, and tick which series you would like plotted on a second axis, and which chart types you would like. See image below for reference.

[image]